# Save a value to disk XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a pretty simple task that I'm trying to accomplish in Objective-C.

I make a call to a web site, and get a value from the web site through an HTTP call. I want to save this value to disk so I can retrieve it later.

What would be the best method to do this - a text file, or in the PList file?

It's just one value that may occasionally be updated. The call to the web site is made on-demand.

Comment: [NSUserDefaults]https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html if its a small value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using `NSUserDefaults` for storing single values

*For Storing:*

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:100 forKey:@"storageKey"];
```

*For Retrieving:*

```
NSInteger myValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:storageKey];
```